# Go through a 2 dimensional array in C

Tags: c, turbo-c

I want to print a two dimensional array's value, one by one.
But my code shows one item many times :(

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

void main()
{
    char words[][5]={"Hiii","Hello"};
    int size;
    char *cp,*p;
    p=words;
    clrscr();
    printf("%p ",p);
    size=sizeof(words);
    printf("Size %d\n",size);
    for(cp=p;cp<(p+size);cp++)
        printf("%s ",cp);
    getch();
}
```

Expected o/p
Hiii
Hello

Unexpected o/p
Hiii
iii
ii
i

Hello
ello
llo
lo
o

Comment: Please add "homework" tag if it is homework. So far it is unclear why you expect "expected" output for the given code.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov It's not a h/w, I'm stuck in this level, but i need to show something like "expected" !

Comment: @Sourav: post a compilable program sample. The output you have posted does not even belong to the program.Where are the prints for size of array? Paste atleast complete o/p.

Comment: @Als I compiled the code in "Borland Turbo C" not in GCC. "The output you have posted does not even belong to the program." why do u t hink so :O ?

Comment: Already stated why, in the previous comment, there are some obvious printf statements missing.

Comment: @Als You must 've missed it ! It was there just before **getch();**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the array `words` is laid out in memory like

```
Hiii\0Hello
```

Also, since `cp` is a pointer to `char`, the expression `cp++` increments `cp` by exactly on byte. That's you're printing `"Hiii"`, followed by `"iii"` then `"ii"` and `"i"`. For correctness, `cp++` should be changed to `cp += 5`.

Finally, the array is incorrectly sized. The length of `"Hiii"` is `5` and the length of `"Hello"` is `6`, since there is an implicit null terminator `\0` at the end of each string. So `words` should actually be declared as `char words[][6]={"Hiii","Hello"};`. This also means that `cp` should now be incremented by `6` each time.

With the corrections made, the `for` loop becomes

```
for(cp=p;cp<(p+size);cp+=6)
  printf("%s ",cp);
```

To make you life easier, since you're working with an array, you can make use of indices rather the relying on pointer arithmetic:

```
int strCount = size / 6; // since each element of words is 6 characters long
for(int i = 0; i < strCount; i++)
    printf("%s ", cp);
```

Comment: Thanks a ton, but is there any way to find the "6" automatically ?

Comment: @Sourav: Not with your current code structure. You can declare a constant, say `STRING_SIZE` which has the value 6. Then each `6` can be replaced with `STRING_SIZE`. This allows you to update the string size in a uniform manner.

Comment: @KenWayneVanderLinde  *the array words is laid out in memory like `Hiii\0Hello\0`* this is wrong: in C it is laid out like `Hiii\0Hello` and in C++ it would be not valid as it there must be enough room for the string in the declaration.

Answer (score 0):

You are using ("%s ",cp) - prints null terminated string starting form `cp`, when you want print a character `cp` points to.

Comment: Okk, but %c does not work either :( . But how to get the desired output ?

Answer (score 0):

```
 char words[][5]={"Hiii", "Hello"};
```

The string literal `Hello` is 6 characters long (including the null character) but it is initializing an array of type `char[5]` (remember `words` is an array 2 of array 5 of `char`).

When a string literal is used to initialize an array of fixed size (here the `char[5]` array), only the the number of elements that fit into the array are used to initialize the array.

That is, the memory layout of `words` is:

```
Hiii\0Hello
```

the terminating null character of `"Hello"` is not copied, as it does not fit into the `char[5]` object.

(Note that this is true for C, in C++ it would not be valid to initialize an array with a string literal with more characters that the number of elements in the array).

In your case, you want to make some room for the terminated null character of `"Hello"` and so you should declare `words` as:

```
 char words[][6]={"Hiii", "Hello"};
              ^ instead of 5
```